# How to seed database data for integration testing in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, integration-testing, fluent-migrator

I've been writing some integration tests recently against ASP.Net MVC controller actions and have been frustrated by the difficulty in setting up the test data that needs to be present in order to run the test.

For example, I want to test the "add", "edit" and "delete" actions of a controller. I can write the "add" test fine, but then find that to write the "edit" test I was am either going to have to call the code of the "add" test to create a record so that I can edit it, or do a lot of setup in the test class, neither of which are particularly appealing.

Ideally I want to use or develop an integration test framework to make it easier to add seed data in a reusable way for integration tests so that the arrange aspect of an arrange/act/assert test can focus on arranging what I specifically need to arrange for my test rather than concerning itself with arranging a load of reference data only indirectly related to the code under the test.

I happen to be using NHibernate but I believe any data seeding functionality should be oblivious to that and be able to manipulate the database directly; the ORM may change, but I will allways be using a SQL database.

I'm using NUnit so envisage hooking into the test/testfixture setup/teardown (but I think a good solution would potentially transferable to other test frameworks).

I'm using [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki) in my main project to manage schema and seeding of reference data so it would be nice, but not essential to be able to use the FluentMigrator framework for a consistent approach across the solution.

So my question is, "How do you seed your database data for integration testing in C#?" Do you execute the SQL directly? Do you use a framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your integration testing on Sql Server Compact, you will have a .sdf file and you can connect to it giving the file's path as connection string. That would be faster and easier to setup and work with.

Your integration test would not probably need millions of rows of data. You can insert your test data into your database and save it as `TestDbOriginal.sdf`.

When you are running your tests, just make a copy of this '`TestDbOriginal.sdf`' and work on that copy, which is already seeded with data. If you want to test a specific scenario, you will need to prepare your data by calling some methods like add, remove, edit .

When you go production or performance testing, switch back to your original server version, be it Sql Server 2008 or whatever.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? Are you suggesting the OP should switch DB platform just for the purpose of testing?

Comment: You can see this approach in many popular open source projects. I've also used this approach in some of my projects. What is the drawback in your terms? Btw, "just for testing" sounds weird.

Comment: Isn't it a better idea to test your application using the database platform that it is intended for and will be released on? Whats the point of migrating your database to CE and testing it there? Seems like a waste of time to me.

Comment: As its name implies, it is compact. It is faster, easy to handle, setup and connect. Just give the file's name and you are connected. You don't spend any additional time, just give the path to .sdf file instead of connection string to sql server, and you are good to go. Checkout http://www.differentpla.net/content/2009/03/using-sql-server-compact-edition-unit-testing

Comment: Thanks @Mert. This is certainly a valid approach, and one that I've used before. The drawbacks that I encountered with this were;

1) Because the test data is persisted in the database it effectively becomes shared test data. In a multi developer environment it's too easy for other developers to hijack the test data that was specific to my test for their own purposes. 2) When running a lot of integration tests there's a big performance hit if the database has to be restored between tests or test fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's necessarily the 'right' thing to do, but I've always seeded using my add/create method(s).

Comment: Thanks @mattyB, that's directly related to my quesion; if the logic pf the add action is broken, should this break my edit test too? I believe tests should be isolated where possible. If the add action is broken (and I _should_ have a separate test for that) should this cause the edit action fail too? The edit test shouldn't be coupled tot the add test.

Comment: @Tristan, if you're populating your test database from within your SetUp method, then potentially _all_ your tests will fail if the Create action is not working. That's why I always implement my Create method(s) first (plus tests), make sure they're working and then use them to populate the database for testing. Then I can write tests and implement methods in my DAO safe in the knowledge that my Create methods is okay and any failures are being caused by the method-under-test.